# Using a fractional argument when dereferencing an array in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I like to ask that what happens if we pass a fractional number when dereferencing an array in C or C++. An example of what I mean:

```
int arr1[],arr2[];
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    arr1[i]=i;
  else 
    arr2[i/2]=i;
}
```

What would be the compiler do when it sees `arr2[3/2]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i/2` is integer division. The result of this division will again be an integer, namely the result of the division truncated towards 0. (`3/2==1; -5/2==-2;`) So you will not be passing a fraction to an array-index.

If you try to pass a data type which can be a fraction (for example a `double`), the compiler will generate an error.

Comment: It's truncated, not rounded down. The difference is with things like (-1)/2, which, when truncated, produces 0, but rounded down produces -1.

Answer (score 1):

The division would happen first, and the answer would then be used as the array index. So, in your example, `3/2` would resolve to `1` (truncation), and then it would assign `arr2[1]=i`.

Comment: To TBS: I'm sure that you know it, but your wording is misleading. To @exploringnet: There is no "truncation". This is integer division and integer result. The 3/2 is immediatelly computed as 1. There is no 'fraction'/'truncation' step.

Comment: Ok,but what is truncation in cpp

Comment: @quetzalcoatl - the language definition disagrees with you. "For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded; (footnote: This is often called truncation towards zero)." [expr.mul] /4.

Comment: It is mathematical truncation, not computational truncation. I am well aware that it "instantly" resolves to `1`.

Comment: @PeteBecker - True, but missed! Language definition describes the result, not **how** it is performed. If you ever happen to see a non-esoteric C++ compiler that performs it that way (instead of bitshifts or integerdivision opcodes), please let me know! :) TheBuzzSaw - I've never implied you are not (see first sentence). I've just sensed that exploringnet might be not, hence I tried to expand your words, for him.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl - yes, the language definition describes the result, and it uses the word "truncation". Saying that there is no truncation is simply wrong. If you want to say that typical hardware doesn't use a separate step to truncate, by all means do so. But regardless of how it's accomplished, the result is truncated.

Comment: @PeteBecker: ah, now I see it. You've got your point in my fast typing. I was sure I said "truncation step" twice, this is what I meant all the time. I've ommitted the word "step" in the first sentence. Of course, truncation occurs - but only logically.

Answer (score 0):

3/2 yields an integer result equal to 1. There is no 'fraction' in such line, ever.

```
arr2[3/2] ==== arr2[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. array index should be integer. If you use a float type, it would be cast to an integer.
2. integer1 / integer2 yields another integer in c/c++.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the compiler do when it sees arr2[3/2]?

The compiler would do nothing. The expression "3/2" is valid and will result in an integer at runtime.